# Unwanted symbol result when evaluating postfix expression

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to make a C program to evaluate postfix expressions and when doing so an unwanted symbol is being printed on the screen for the input 45+.
P.S. Please tell me the mistake (except of that gets() I am studying right now how to use fgets())

```
// to Evaluate a postfix expression
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int is_operator(char);
void answer();
char stack[100];
int top =-1;
void push(char);
char pop();
void main()
{
char postfix[100],item;
int i=0;
clrscr();
printf("Enter Postfix Expression");
gets(postfix);
while(postfix[i]!='\0')
    {
    item=postfix[i];
    if(is_operator(item)==2)
        {
        push(item);
        }
    if(is_operator(item)==1)
        {
        char op;
        int n1,n2,n3;
        op=item;
        n1=pop();
        n2=pop();
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
            n3=n1+n2;
            case '-':
            n3=n1-n2;
            case '*':
            n3=n1*n2;
            case '/':
            n3=n1/n2;
        }
        push(n3);
        }
    i++;
    }//end while
answer();
getch();
}
void push(char c)
{
top++;
stack[top]=c;
}
char pop()
{
char c;
c=stack[top];
top--;
return(c);
}
int is_operator(char i)
{
char ch=i;
if(ch=='+'||ch=='-'||ch=='*'||ch=='/')
    {
    return(1);
    }
else
    {
    return(2);
    }
}
void answer()
{
char ans;
ans=stack[top];
printf("Answere is %c",ans);
}
```

Comment: Could you also hereby attach the current output and expected output? (by [edit]ing your question)

Comment: If you never used a debugger before, now is the perfect time to start. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while at the same time monitoring variables and their values and how they change. By doing that you should easily be able to find out where it happens, and hopefully why as well.

Comment: Current Output is unwanted symbol like a smilley face And Wanted Output is 9 @JonnyHenly

Comment: Here's a hint for you: You are dealing with *characters* and not integers. You might want to check e.g. [an ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) to see the *actual* values you are working with.

Comment: Like Joachim Pileborg suggested you really should learn to use a debugger, it will be incredibly beneficial in the future. That being said, I believe `gets(...)` is also accepting the enter key being pressed as input. You should change your while loop statement to `while(postfix[i] != '\0' && postfix[i] != '\n')` and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.Try to properly type cast.

Go through comments to understand the mistakes.

Go through [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-pointers-fundamentals) for understanding character pointer and arrays.

// to Evaluate a postfix expression

```
#include<stdio.h>



int is_operator(char);
void answer();
int stack[100];//Use integer array since operands are integer
int top =-1;
void push(int);//Arguments changed to integer type since the stack is integer 
int pop(); //Return type to integer
void main()
{
char* postfix;//Use character pointer for iterating through loop smoothly
 int item;
int i=0;

printf("Enter Postfix Expression");
gets(postfix);
char c;

while(*postfix!='\0')
    {
    c=*postfix;
    if(is_operator(c)==2)
        {
        push((c-'0')); //Converting char to int before pushing it into the stack
        }
    if(is_operator(c)==1)
        {


        char op;
        int n1,n2,n3;
        op=*postfix;
        n1=pop();
        n2=pop();
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
            n3=n1+n2;
            break;
            case '-':
            n3=n1-n2;
            break;
            case '*':
            n3=n1*n2;
            break;
            case '/':
            n3=n1/n2;
            break;
        }
        push(n3);
        }
    postfix++;
    }//end while
answer();

}
void push(int c)
{
top++;
stack[top]=c;
}
int pop()
{
int c;
c=stack[top];
top--;
return(c);
}
int is_operator(char i)
{
char ch=i;
if(ch=='+'||ch=='-'||ch=='*'||ch=='/')
    {
    return(1);
    }
else
    {
    return(2);
    }
}
void answer()
{
char ans;
ans=stack[top];
printf("Answere is %d",ans);
}
```

I hope it is helpful....

Answer (score 0):

The problems I see with your code are: your `switch()` is missing `break` statements on the individual `case` clauses (and a `default` case might be nice too); when you push your non-operators (aka single digit numbers) on the stack, you push them as character codes rather then converting them to numbers so the math doesn't make sense; you're not properly handling the order of non-communitive operations like subtraction and division (use Unix `dc` command as a comparison tool); finally, don't reinvent booleans.  Below is a rework of your code with the above changes and some style adjustments:

```
// Evaluate a postfix expression

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char stack[100];
int top = -1;

void push(char);
char pop(void);
bool is_operator(char);
void answer(void);

void push(char c)
{
    stack[++top] = c;
}

char pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}

bool is_operator(char op)
{
    return (op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/');
}

void answer()
{
    printf("Answer is %d\n", stack[top]);
}

int main()
{
    char item, postfix[100];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter Postfix Expression: ");

    gets(postfix);

    while ((item = postfix[i++]) != '\0')
    {
        if (is_operator(item))
        {
            char n1 = pop();
            char n2 = pop();
            char n3 = 0;

            switch (item)
            {
                case '+':
                    n3 = n1 + n2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    n3 = n2 - n1;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    n3 = n1 * n2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    n3 = n2 / n1;
                    break;
            }

            push(n3);
        } else if (isdigit(item)) {
            push(item - '0');
        }
    } // end while
    answer();

    return 0;
}
```

Example (note this evaluator only operates on single digit numbers):

```
> ./a.out
Enter Postfix Expression: 6 4 - 7 * 1 +
Answer is 15
> dc
6 4 - 7 * 1 + p
15
```

Comment: In the is_operator function why are you returning an operator(op) while the return type is int

In the answer function why you have used %d as the stack array is of character type.

Comment: @user6547375, `is_operator()` doesn't return an operator, it returns *true* or *false*, as we would expect of a function that starts with `is_`, i.e. asks a question.  To make this more explicit, I've included the stdbool library and changed the return type to `bool`.  The stack array consists of numbers, they just happen to be signed 8bit numbers declared as `char`.  When printing the result on the stack we want the number that results from the calculation, `%d`, not the ASCII character, `%c`, that maps to that result.